# How do I make Buttons in Wordpress site?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, button

Hi guys I almost have a finished website done by a friend of mine. And now I want to help him by doing the terms of use, privacy and so on pages that lie at the end of the page. Sounds quite easy but it's my first time doing it.

So, how do I create this kind of simple buttons that will connect with the terms of use, privacy and so on pages in a Wordpress site? If anybody can help me will really appreciate it, thank you for your time

Comment: Basicallly in the WP Backend you have the possibility to add items on your menu(s). Simply drag and drop your pages (AGB, etc.) into the desired menu. NOTE: The appearance of the menus in the frontend depends on the used theme.

Comment: Yes I could add them in the menu of the theme, but I want it to be independent and be at the bottom of the page, like on other websites, the privacy, terms of use lay at the bottom. If I add them in the current menu it won't be ok.

Comment: You can directly add them in footer.php file of theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options at hand:
**Add a footer menu** - If your theme already supports a footer menu then all you need to do is log into the Wordpress CMS, go to appearance->menus, select the footer menu and add those pages. If your theme doesn't support a footer menu you can add one by registering a [new navigation menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus) and then adding the menu to your footer using the [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function.


**Add a filter** - if your purpose is to append these links right after the content of the pages you can use the_content filter.


**Add the links directly to the footer** - You can hardcode the links by simply finding your footer file and adding them there. This is a quick and dirty solution. Quick because it requires no PHP or Wordpress knowledge whatsoever, but dirty because you are hardcoding the links and your friend will not be able to change or edit them later via the Wordpress CMS (unless you add them as options, but that's just overkill in your case).

Comment: Thanks Will add it using the Wordpress CMS.